# Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1 running Xcode project

Tags: xcode, macos, keychain, sign, openframeworks

I am trying to run my openFrameworks project in xcode. I have been able to do this up until now and Im not sure what has changed.

I now get this error when trying to run my project:

```
CodeSign bin/Part1Debug.app
    cd "/Users/jimmyneutron/Documents/xxx/yyy/zzz/of_v0.10.1_osx_release/apps/myApps/Part1"
    export CODESIGN_ALLOCATE=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/codesign_allocate

Signing Identity:     "-"

    /usr/bin/codesign --force --sign - --entitlements /Users/jimmyneutron/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Part1-brbngmytvgzsunfpniznbqfhlbdf/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Part1.build/Debug/Part1.build/Part1Debug.app.xcent --timestamp=none /Users/jimmyneutron/Documents/xxx/yyy/zzz/of_v0.10.1_osx_release/apps/myApps/Part1/bin/Part1Debug.app

/Users/jimmyneutron/Documents/xxx/yyy/zzz/of_v0.10.1_osx_release/apps/myApps/Part1/bin/Part1Debug.app: code object is not signed at all
In subcomponent: /Users/jimmyneutron/Documents/xxx/yyy/zzz/of_v0.10.1_osx_release/apps/myApps/Part1/bin/Part1Debug.app/Contents/Frameworks/libfmodex.dylib
Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1
```

I have tried changing my keychain password, but when I click 'Edit' in Keychain, the option 'Change password for keychain login' is greyed out.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because Xcode was (automatically) updated. The new version requires signed dynamic libraries.   The nightly version of openFrameworks includes a signed version of libfmodex.dylib. To fix this problem you can downgrade Xcode, manually replace your version libfmodex.dylib from the OF nighty build, or just use a nighty build. The next official release will solve this problem.

More info

https://forum.openframeworks.cc/t/cant-run-examples-in-xcode-signing-issue-with-libfmodex-dylib/33463